# WPF DataGrid hide selection buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to use the WPF DataGrid to present a completely static, flat and readonly columnar view.

I've tried the `ListView` with a `GridView` as well, but that offers less styling options.

Here's what I've got so far:

[image: Screenshot]

Unfortunately this still has some strange buttons in the columns and on each row (the grey sections).

I've set `IsHitTestVisible` to false to prevent the user clicking them, but ideally I'd like for them to not be there (or at the very least be invisible).

Here's the XAML styling I'm applying:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGrid}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

This is practically perfect apart from those buttons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are row headers, not buttons I think. The Datagrid has a property to show/hide row and column headers:

```
<Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
```

Actually the value needs to be column, if you want to keep the column headers.